# AS3 9 slice scaling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, components

i'm making window component on Flash Professional CS4 and now i have 1 problem. At the top  of window is dynamic textfield for title. When i scale window text is also scaling. So is there any way to make textfield fixed in same position and same size?

P.S. 9-slice scaling is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate your window's background from the rest of it:

```
window > title
       > background
```

Your background would be the only clip to be 9-sliced and you will scale your window by doing:

```
window.getChildByName("background").scaleX = newScaleX;
window.getChildByName("background").scaleY = newScaleY;
```

Answer (score 0):

When window is scaled (`widow.scale = newScale`) all you need is to do `textfield.scale = 1 / scale`

Comment: Thanks, but what about child MCs? Child MCs scales ignoring parent's 9slice scaling guides. Is there any solution?

Comment: you can scale MCs programaticaly as well.